# dynamic text moving other text

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, so I know this is probably simple but I'm having such a brain fart... I have a div with text in it and inside it a dynamic text that changes. The problem is that when the text changes, it is moving my other text. I have tried putting it as fixed...with fixes the problem, however, at a later time when i add more content that will involve scrolling, i know that the fixed text will remain there the entire scrolling.... so i'm trying to get the same thing that fixed is offering but allowing it to scroll. Here is some code:

pretty much if I change the dynamicText to position:fixed; then everything on the left side stays still....but I think I should use a different way but don't know how. Thanks in advance

HTML:

```
<div class="message">
            Hi, my name is <span class="title">Carine.</span> I'm a 
            <span class="title dynamicText"> Web Developer.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.message {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 3% auto;
}
.title {
    font-family: 'Over the Rainbow', cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.dynamicText {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 550ms ease;  
    -moz-transition: opacity 550ms ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 550ms ease;
    transition: opacity 550ms ease;
}

.dynamicTextOff {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    runSkills();
}

runSkills = function() {
var array = [
    "Graphic Designer.",
    "UX Designer.",
    "Photographer.",
    "Consultant.",
    "Artist.",
    "Jill of all Trades."
];

var i = -1;
var dyText = $(".dynamicText:last");
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    dyText.text(array[i]);
    if(i == array.length-1)
        i = -1;
}, 3100);

var innerInt = setInterval(function() {
    dyText.toggleClass('dynamicTextOff');
}, 1550);
}
```

Comment: so, this message div sits in the middle of the page with margin:auto and therefore its positioning is based on its content width. probably the best solution is to figure out the longest bit of text and set the dynamictext span to be display:inline-block; width: 100px (or what ever the width needs to be)

Comment: I'll try that thanks.... by the way..another small issue I encountered unrelated to this one is that even though I have html and body height = 100%...sometimes the divs that extend longer don't make them grow...so the background stops short...any idea why this would happen. If i set body and html to auto, it fixes it but I'm not sure if that is the correct answer

Comment: the 100% is related to the window height. i don't really use that technique for that fact. look at setting the background position fixed with top 0, left 0, height and width 100%. got to sleep!

Comment: hey, if anyone has a chance and likes to code review...here is my site www.gravityvisuals.com.  I'd really appreciate a code review when it comes to the responsiveness and media queries. I'm learning .